# How can I write the trace, console and error outputs into my XML report file?

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I want the *Trace*, *Console* and *Console Error* outputs would be written into the common XML report file (for example into *cad.UnitTests.xml*). By default this info is not written in XML.

[image]

How can I do it? `nunit-console.exe` has such parameters:

```
/output=STR  File to receive test output (Short format: /out=STR)
/err=STR  File to receive test error output
```

But I need to get it *in the same XML file*. I need it for both cases: `nunit-console.exe` and `nunit.exe`. Also, I looked the settings of GUI NUnit but found nothing.

My BAT file has such content:

```
:: run_me.bat
:: © Andrey Bushman, 2015
ECHO OFF

CD /D %~dp0
SET file_name=cad.UnitTests

:: Run NUnit tests
call "%NUNIT%\nunit-console.exe" ^
  /out="%~dp0%file_name%_out.txt" ^
  /err="%~dp0%file_name%_err.txt" ^
  /trace=Verbose ^
  /noshadow ^
  /xml="%~dp0%file_name%.xml" ^
  "%~dp0%file_name%.dll"

:: Get the HTML report of the unit testing
call "%ReportUnit%\ReportUnit.exe" ^
  "%~dp0%file_name%.xml" ^
  "%~dp0%file_name%.html"
```

But even if I use such command:

```
call "%NUNIT%\nunit-console.exe" ^
  /out="%~dp0%file_name%_out.txt" ^
  /err="%~dp0%file_name%_err.txt" ^
  /noshadow ^
  /xml="%~dp0%file_name%.xml" ^
  "%~dp0%file_name%.dll"
```

then the *Trace* output is absent in both files (the *"%~dp0%file_name%_out.txt"* and *"%~dp0%file_name%_err.txt"*).

I don't see of `nunit-console.exe` option for *Trace output* redirection (something like `/traceFile`). I see the `/trace` parameter, but it has other purpose.

It is necessary for me, because I use the result XML for generation of HTML through the [ReportUnit.exe](http://relevantcodes.com/reportunit-report-generator/). I want to see the detailed info in the HTML.

I can save the Trace output into TXT file in the code of my unit tests:

```
/* SetUpClass.cs
 * © Andrey Bushman, 2015
 */

namespace Bushman.CAD.UnitTests {
  using System;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using NUnit.Framework;

  [SetUpFixture]
  public class SetUpClass {

    private TextWriterTraceListener listener = null;

    [SetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests() {
      Stream traceFile = File.Create("trace_out.txt");
      listener = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceFile);
      Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void RunAfterAnyTests() {
      listener.Flush();
    }
  }
}
```

But I still have a hope what I can to get this info in the XML file (which is generated by NUnit) through the "native" way of NUnit.